# How can I do the following query to get needed information

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables

- `CompList` table with following columns : `CompId` , `McID` , `station` , `slot` ,`subslot` , and several others
- `BookingTable` with columns: `CompId` , `LineID` , `McID` , `station` , `slot` ,`subslot`.

I want to get following result:

rows only that `CompList.CompId == BookingTable.CompId` (only CompId that is in both tables)

and I need in the result columns from `CompList`: `CompId` , `McID` , `station` , `slot` ,`subslot` and from `BookingTable`:  `LineID` , `McID` , `station` , `slot` ,`subslot`

And how will I be able to distinguish between same columns with same table in the result table  them in the result table?

Thanks for help.

Comment: you could ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT 
    CL.CompId,
    CL.McID,
    CL.station,
    CL.slot,
    CL.subslot,
    BT.LineID,
    BT.McID     as BookingMcId, 
    BT.station  as BookingStation, 
    BT.slot     as BookingSlot, 
    BT.subslot  as BookingSubslot
FROM CompList as CL
JOIN BookingTable as BT ON BT.CompId = CL.CompId
```

Answer (score 2):

preface all column names with table name in your select statement, and use aliases to disambiguate the columns in the result set:

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_alias.asp

that said, i am unclear on why you have so much seemingly redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.CompId,c.D,c.station,c.slot,c.subslot,b.neID,b.McID,b.station,b.slot,b.subslot from CompList c join BookingTable b on c.ComId=b.CompId
```

Answer (score 0):

You do an inner join between the tables and you use column alias to distinguish between columns with the same name from different tables.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx

```
select T1.Name as T1Name, T2.Name as T2Name
from T1
  inner join T2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   cl.CompId , cl.McID , cl.station, cl.slot, cl.subslot, 
   bt.LineID, bt.McID, bt.station, bt.slot, bt.subslot 
FROM 
   CompList cl 
INNER JOIN 
   BookingTable bt ON cl.McID=bt.McID
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, to distinguish columns of CompList and BookingTable use alias name for the columns you want to get in the result.

Eg: Let there are two table t1 & t2, both having same names in cols say cid, name, roll and address.

to get t1.cid == t2.cid (only cid that is in both tables)

we write: select t1.cid, 
        t1.name as name1,
        t1.roll as roll1,
        t1.address as address1,
        t2.name as name2,
        t2.roll as roll2,
        t2.address as address2
    from t1, t2 
where t1.cid=t2.cid;